# Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read (ES14.6E2)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to execute a Fortran code and I get the following error:

> At line 79 of file src/annGeneralization.f90 (unit = 12, file = './output/ann1_1.out')
> Fortran runtime error: Bad value during floating point read

And this is how the lines 77, 78 and 79 of my annGeneralization.f90 file looks like:

```
        write(*,*) './output/ann' // trim(str1) // '_' // trim(str0) // '.out'
        open(12, FILE = './output/ann' // trim(str1) // '_' // trim(str0) // '.out')
        read(12, '(ES14.6E2)') fitness
```

Looking here, what is a problem with my input file format, but I'm not very experienced in fortran, I've tried everything. My ann1_1.out input file is:

[image: ann1_1.out]

Comment: Please tell us what the first line of that input file is.

Comment: Please do not share the input file in external storage sites like Google Drive. If it is a text file, just copy and paste the relevant part of the file right here into your question as text. Use [edit] to add the data now. It is very important, the question must remain valid also in the future and the files in external sites often get deleted. See also [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: the fist line: Objective Function (MPCA):   6.653589E-02

Comment: You can’t read a character (“Objective”) into a real variable (fitness), but that is what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Also, even just for the number specifying the exact width in the format as 14 ` '(ES14.6E2)'` is unlikely to work and the other numbers are weirdly chosen. There is little reason to choose the `es` descriptor at all. This file is not in specific columns and the fixed column format is unlikely to be helpful here in general. The parsing will have to take a very different approach. I suggest to read at least some very basics about parsing data files. Nothing complicated about context free grammars, but some basics how to read a line and how to find the number in the line and get the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some choice over the matter then I wouldn't have input files where the data that you want is right at the end of a line after an unknown-length descriptor. Fortran makes it much easier if the data is the first thing in the record.

However, if you are stuck with the format of the input file then you can read the whole line in one go (for which you will need an 'a' format specifier), find the position of a separator (':' would work in your case), read the actual character substring after this separator (this is called an "internal file" in Fortran) into your data variable.

I think this is best done in a separate subroutine (and, sadly, in the absence of template procedures you are going to need a different one for integer data).

```
subroutine readParameter( unit, separator, description, value )
   implicit none
   integer, intent(in) :: unit                             
   character, intent(in) :: separator
   character(len=*), intent(out) :: description
   real, intent(out) :: value

   character(len=100) line
   integer i

   read( unit, "(a)" ) line                      ! Read a single line
   i = index( line, separator )                  ! Find the separator, here ":"
   description = line(1:i-1)                     ! The description comes before the sparator
   read( line(i+1:), * ) value                   ! The rest of the line contains your data

end subroutine readParameter


program test
   implicit none

   character(len=72) description
   real value
   character, parameter :: separator = ":"
   character(len=*), parameter :: filename = "ann1_1.out"
   character(len=*), parameter :: fmt = "( 'Description: ', a, /, 'Value: ', es12.5 )"

   open( 10, file=filename )
   call readParameter( 10, separator, description, value )
   write( *, fmt ) description, value
   close( 10 )

end program test
```

Output:

```
Description: Objective Function (MPCA)                                               
Value:  6.65359E-02
```